# An SVM that has the capabilities to perform "online learning" and give probability to a prediction using hinge loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

There is a bit of a dilemma with sklearn.

Using [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) I can use the method `predict_proba` to calculate how likely a prediction is.

Using [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) I can perform "online/incremental" learning using the method `partial_fit` method but `predict_proba` doesn't work with the 'hinge' `loss`.

Is there anyway to have both?

Answer (score 1):

As someone asked about that before [@github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7278), the authors then [added](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7281) mentioning of this to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba).

So your doc-entry to go for is sklearn's [Probability calibration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibration).

A basic example was given in the github link as:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge')
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=5, method='sigmoid')
calibrated_clf.fit(X, y)
```

**But** this probably won't work for `partial_fit` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9538).

So for your task it's important to know if the following works for you:

> no, you can't partial_fit the calibration, but you can partial_fit the
>   underlying classifier

Comment: I am confused. In the above code snippet `clf` will not be modified after the initial `.fit`? So why would I apply `patial_fit` to that? Could I `partial_fit` the `clf` and then "turn it into" a `CalibratedClassifierCV`?

Comment: I see you can set `cv` to `prefit`. So if I run partial fit on `clf` and then any time I want to run `.predict_proba` I just run `CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv='prefit', method='sigmoid').predict_proba(...` does that work?

Comment: Would you be able to explain this to me?